# Unfortunately android app has stopped when running

Tags: android

I have an android application but when I want to run this application the emulator stopped the compilation by: Unfortunately android app has stopped

this is the Logcat file:

```
07-14 14:27:09.867: D/AndroidRuntime(1450): Shutting down VM
07-14 14:27:09.867: W/dalvikvm(1450): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.peoplesqlite/com.example.peoplesqlite.MainActivity}:   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:102)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at com.example.peoplesqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-14 14:27:09.887: E/AndroidRuntime(1450):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Consider posting the code from your MainActivity.

Comment: (-1) A stack trace is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an empty string to Integer.parseInt(), add a check for null or empty before calling that method.